# "Non-mainstream chemistry" questions

Tags: discussion

On the tour of Chem SE I saw a guideline about *not* asking "Non-mainstream chemistry" questions. What exactly would non-mainstream questions be?

Answer (score 8):

As [Potter Stewart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it) once said "[We] know it when [we] see it."

I don't think we have any set criteria for this, but, in broad strokes, we're talking about speculative things like "What would Martian nucleotides look like?" or "Can I create [X] using alchemy?"  I know the latter has some historical significance for chemistry, so questions regarding how that influenced modern methods would be okay.

Those are a couple of examples that I can come up with offhand.  Really we mean anything that is overly-speculative, rooted in fiction, or that has largely been long disproven by fact doesn't really belong an a site that is seeking to be a repository for solid chemistry knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

While we don't have a fixed policy for it yet (if there are cases where the community is undecided on the mainstreamness, we can come up with one),
 [the relevant policy on Physics.SE](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/is-non-mainstream-physics-appropriate-for-this-site) should give a good approximation to what we define as non mainstream.